# Query takes longer time in Oracle18C compared to Oracle 12C

Tags: database, oracle

A `select` query which used to take 2 minutes on **Oracle 12C** is taking about 10 days in **Oracle 18C**.
The query is selecting distinct rows from two `force editionable` views.

Can anyone give hints on how to proceed with this?

Comment: For a start, look at the actual execution plans. Maybe Real Time Sql Monitoring (RTSM) will be of use too.

Comment: As tuning can be a lengthy conversation with multiple iterations, if you'd like to try to understand and fix the problem "off-line", send me a message and we can work it from there.

Comment: @JimWartnick : How do I can approach you 'off-line'?

Comment: @JimWartnick: Thank you. I have noted down the id. I will approach you through that. Just to make your inbox spam-free, please delete/edit your comment and remove your email-id from it.

Comment: @JimWartnick: Can you please have a look into your inbox? :-|